# Adding timezone to time in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timezone, pytz

I have my column with time in seconds. And timezone of this time is in UTC but Pandas doesn't know it. I would like to add this information.

```
df_data['transaction_creation_date']

0        1484161304
1        1489489785
2        1489161124
3        1488904824
4        1484908677
5        1485942900
6        1490854506
7        1485895432
8        1485975392
9        1489266328
10       1488525196
11       1490363033
12       1490617794
13       1486560642
14       1487170224
15       1484923852
```

So I do something like this:

```
df_times = pd.DatetimeIndex(pd.to_datetime(df_data['transaction_creation_date'], unit='s'))
df_times = df_times.tz_localize(pytz.utc)
```

And when I print timestamps stored in `df_times` then I have:

```
print(df_times.strftime('%s'))

['1484157704' '1489486185' '1489157524' ..., '1490684098' '1490284646'
 '1489602636']
```

So...

My UTC time on row 0: `1484161304` after I have added information about timezone got changed to `1484157704`...

My timezone is "Europe/Warsaw" and difference between my timezone and UTC is `3600` while `1484161304 - 1484157704 = 3600`.

So pandas has treated my UTC times as it were "Europe/Warsaw" and switched them one hour behind to make them UTC which corrupted my data.

How can I set UTC timezone to my times so it doesn't happen?

Answer (score 0):

So I was unable to replicate your results, but I am using a slightly different method to show the created timestamp.  I did not use the somewhat poorly supported `%s`, and instead directly calculated the number of seconds from UTC epoch:

**Code:**

```
utc_at_epoch = pytz.utc.localize(dt.datetime(1970, 1, 1))
for t in df_times.tz_localize(pytz.utc):
    print(int((t - utc_at_epoch).total_seconds()))
```

**Test Code:**

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
import pytz

df_data = pd.DataFrame([
    1484161304,
    1489489785,
    1489161124,
], columns=['transaction_creation_date'])
print(df_data)

df_times = pd.DatetimeIndex(pd.to_datetime(
    df_data['transaction_creation_date'], unit='s'))

utc_at_epoch = pytz.utc.localize(dt.datetime(1970, 1, 1))
for t in df_times.tz_localize(pytz.utc):
    print(int((t - utc_at_epoch).total_seconds()))
```

**Results:**

```
   transaction_creation_date
0                 1484161304
1                 1489489785
2                 1489161124
1484161304
1489489785
1489161124
```

Comment: Thanks for response. I will take a closer look at it soon. For now I have "workarounded" my code with: `os.environ['TZ'] = 'UTC'`. Thanks to that my UTC timestamps are not changed (according to my tz -> Europe/Warsaw) after I use .tz_localize(pytz.utc) as there is no time difference between UTC and UTC timezones.